# Sharing a Uri on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, uri, sharing

I'm looking to add sharing into my game. What I would like to do is allow the user to share his or her top score attached to a link to my game. I've looked at the sharing sample in the developer center, which works for having it attached to a button, but not automatically list it via the share charm.

Any tips on how to achieve this?

Comment: to clarify: you want the share to only work when you hit a button (programmatically), and if it's invoked by the charm directly to indicate there's nothing to share? Otherwise, the [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Source-App-d9bffd84/sourcecode?fileId=43981&pathId=1273416721) (which I think you're referring to) does work via button or just pressing Win+H.

Comment: Actually, I want it to work the other way around. I can get it to work via a button, but would like it to show up in the share charm.

Comment: what do you mean by "show up"? let us know what functionality you're looking for that the [Sharing Content source app](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Target-App-e2689782) does NOT provide.

Answer (score 0):

You should review the Sharing content Quickstart, you need to do a little setup to get this to work, it's all described in the quickstarts.

Here it is for HTMl/JS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465261.aspx
And for C#/XAML: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh871368(v=win.10).aspx

The share text handler includes the text that will be shared in the SetText function call. 
You would put your games store URL in there etc...

```
private void ShareTextHandler(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRequest request = e.Request;
    request.Data.Properties.Title = "Share Text Example";
    request.Data.Properties.Description = "A demonstration that shows how to share text.";
    request.Data.SetText("Hello World!");
}
```